# Heap corruption detected in C++ on delete[] array after copying it

Tags: c++, arrays, pointers, heap-memory, heap-corruption

I'm trying to create a method that create a sort of a dynamic array: when the index exceedes it creates another array with one more element and then it deletes the old one copying the pointer of the new one in the old one. But when I delete the old array I have an HEAP CORRUPTION DETECTED and the program freezes. `states` is the old array (with 10 items) `initializationIndex` is used to keep track of the array length.

```
if (states == nullptr)
    states = new int[10];
if (initializationIndex > 10) {
    int *tempArr = new int[initializationIndex];
    arrayCpy(states, tempArr, initializationIndex - 1);
    delete[] states; // HEAP CORRUPTION DETECTED
    states = tempArr;
}
if (arrayContains(initializationIndex, states, stateToInsert))
    return false;
states[initializationIndex] = stateToInsert;
initializationIndex++;
```

The function arrayCpy:

```
void arrayCpy(int * src, int * dst, int offset)
{
    int i = 0;
    for (i = 0; i < offset; i++) {
        dst[i] = src[i];
    }
}
```

Comment: Use `std::vector`.

Comment: Why are you deleting `tempArr`? shouldn't you be deleting `states`?

Comment: *"...then it deletes the old one..."* - not in this code, it doesn't. You delete the one you just intended to use for expansion.

Comment: This calls for a [mcve].

Comment: if `initializationIndex` is greater than 10 - you are reading out of bounds of `states` array.

Comment: Sorry... I've mistaken: it's `delete[] states` ...

Comment: @GiovanniBertoncelli: It's for exactly these kinds of "misunderstandings" that you are supposed to provide said MCVE! You shouldn't ask here without one.

Comment: Ok I'm sorry... How can I improve the code in this question?

Comment: @GiovanniBertoncelli if you are allowed to use vector please use it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

you edited the question.

```
if (states == nullptr)
    states = new int[10];
if (initializationIndex > 10) {
    int *tempArr = new int[initializationIndex];
    arrayCpy(states, tempArr, initializationIndex - 1);
    delete[] states; // HEAP CORRUPTION DETECTED
    states = tempArr;
}
```

lets assume initializationIndex = 15, you are doing copy for 14 elements while states size is only 10

```
delete[] tempArr; // HEAP CORRUPTION DETECTED
states = tempArr;
```

you delete the array and then use it.

as people said in comments, use std::vector, no need to do new/delete.

Comment: >  no need to do new/delete < except still no education curricula allows use of those classes until they get mentioned in lectures (which usually a few last ones)

Comment: i think it is bad that students learn c++ but use it as C because the syllabus is old and no one want to update it.

Comment: @Arkady Godlin actually it's a problem of mine: I've just started studying this language and I've use it like C because I don't know its potentialities.

Comment: @Arkady Godlin That's not really syllabus being old but a concept of forbidding to use  features that weren't described. It stems from bureaucratic approach of unification of education process.

Comment: @Arkady Godlin It works well with fundamental disciplines, and even in our countries (Russia? Ukraine? Belarus? apparently even France goes that way) the concept of doing this otherwise because "discipline is different" won't roll, because every paper pusher would shoot it down. What they really need is an extensive theoretical part before going practical, but all practices  require to combine both practical and theoretical a same time. Accepting student's work done outside curricula would be "unfair" to students who didn't learn those features yet. That is, from formal point of view.

Comment: @Swift in my university we had much discussion about this. the main argument from the staff was that they have many things to teach and there is no time for all this. which is sad in my opinion.

Comment: "Let's spend a year teaching you how to use C++ wrong" is just outright bad curriculum.

Comment: @Eljay agree, to bad it is hard to change. about once a year in our computer science facebook group comes topic like why we still only use C code, and don't touch c++ at all, or why the first semester course is still in C and not python.